# Use cv2.connectedComponents and eliminate elements with a small number of pixels

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, connected-components

I want to use the function cv2.connectedComponents to connect components on a binary image, like the following...

[image]

I have added the feature to cv2. connectedComponents to eliminate elements with a small number of pixels.

Unfortunately, the algorithm is extremely slow for large images due to the extension. Is there a way to rewrite the extension to speed up the algorithm?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def zerolistmaker(n):
    listofzeros = [0] * n
    return listofzeros


img = cv2.imread('files/motorway/gabor/eGaIy.jpg', 0)

img = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]  # ensure binary
retval, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(img)

##################################################
# ENLARGEMENT
##################################################
sorted_labels = labels.ravel()
sorted_labels = np.sort(sorted_labels)


maxPixel = 50  # eliminate elements with less than maxPixel

# detect how often an element occurs
i=0
counter=0
counterlist = zerolistmaker(retval)

while i < len(sorted_labels):
    if sorted_labels[i] == counter:
        counterlist[counter] = counterlist[counter] + 1
    else:
        counter = counter + 1
        i = i - 1

    i = i + 1


# delete small pixel values
i=0
while i < len(counterlist):
    if counterlist[i] < maxPixel:
        counterlist[i] = 0
    i = i + 1

i=0
counterlisthelper = []
while i < len(counterlist):
    if counterlist[i] == 0:
        counterlisthelper.append(i)
    i = i + 1

i=0
j=0
k=0
while k < len(counterlisthelper):
    while i < labels.shape[0]:
        while j < labels.shape[1]:
            if labels[i,j] == counterlisthelper[k]:
                labels[i,j] = 0
            else:
                labels[i,j] = labels[i,j]
            j = j + 1
        j = 0
        i = i + 1
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = k + 1

##################################################
##################################################

# Map component labels to hue val
label_hue = np.uint8(179*labels/np.max(labels))
blank_ch = 255*np.ones_like(label_hue)
labeled_img = cv2.merge([label_hue, blank_ch, blank_ch])

# cvt to BGR for display
labeled_img = cv2.cvtColor(labeled_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

# set bg label to black
labeled_img[label_hue==0] = 0

cv2.imshow('labeled.png', labeled_img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: 3 nested loops is a horrible thing for python... try to use numpy to replace the values... something like `labels[labels == 3]= 0 `. 3 is one label to be deleted, replace as needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, you should avoid deep loop. Prefer to use `numpy` other than `python-loop`.

Imporved:

```
##################################################
ts = time.time()
num = labels.max()

N = 50

## If the count of pixels less than a threshold, then set pixels to `0`.
for i in range(1, num+1):
    pts =  np.where(labels == i)
    if len(pts[0]) < N:
        labels[pts] = 0

print("Time passed: {:.3f} ms".format(1000*(time.time()-ts)))
# Time passed: 4.607 ms

##################################################
```

---

Result:

[image]
[image]

---

The whole code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2018.01.17 22:36:20 CST
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg', 0)
img = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]  # ensure binary
retval, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(img)

##################################################
ts = time.time()
num = labels.max()

N = 50
for i in range(1, num+1):
    pts =  np.where(labels == i)
    if len(pts[0]) < N:
        labels[pts] = 0

print("Time passed: {:.3f} ms".format(1000*(time.time()-ts)))
# Time passed: 4.607 ms

##################################################

# Map component labels to hue val
label_hue = np.uint8(179*labels/np.max(labels))
blank_ch = 255*np.ones_like(label_hue)
labeled_img = cv2.merge([label_hue, blank_ch, blank_ch])

# cvt to BGR for display
labeled_img = cv2.cvtColor(labeled_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

# set bg label to black
labeled_img[label_hue==0] = 0

cv2.imshow('labeled.png', labeled_img)
cv2.imwrite("labeled.png", labeled_img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Iterating over the whole image for every label is expensive, especially as the number of labels increases.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm very late to this, but I found a solution that is more than twice as fast as the solution by `Kinght 金`. This solution tends to run in around **350ms** on my computer with a **600×800** Image, compared to around **850ms** with the other solution.

#### Function:

```py
def remove_small_groups(image: np.ndarray, minimum: int) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Removes all the groups of connected components smaller than the minimum
    from a binary image

    :param image: The binary image to process
    :param minimum: The minimum size of groups of connected components
    """

    labels, vals = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image)[1:3]
    num = labels.max()

    vals = vals[1:, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA]

    new_img = np.zeros_like(labels)
    for i in filter(lambda v: vals[v] >= minimum, range(0, num)):
        pts = np.where(labels == i + 1)
        new_img[pts] = 255

    return new_img
```

#### Supporting Code:

```py
import numpy as np
import time
import cv2
```

```py
image = cv2.imread('test.jpg', 0)
image = cv2.threshold(img, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

avg_time = 0
for i in range(25):
    ts = time.time()
    vals = x(image, 50)
    avg_time += time.time() - ts

print("Time passed: {:.3f} ms".format(1000 * (avg_time / 25)))
```

Comment: Yes, getting the stats is good. You can make this even faster by creating a map array `map` of size `num+1`, where `map[i]=i` if the `i`th connected component is large enough, and 0 otherwise. Then `map[labels]` should give you the labeled image with small regions removed.

Comment: Cris Luengo, can you elaborate?

Comment: Something like `map = ((vals >= minimum) * 255).astype(np.uint8)` and then `new_img = map[labels]`.